# Would it be any less secure to use Grails 2.4.4 instead of the latest version

Tags: security, grails, grails-2.0, grails-3.0

Would it be any less secure to use Grails 2.4.4 instead of the latest version? (2.4.4 is the latest version I can currently download with Brew). GGTS for eclipse doesn't (currently) support Grails 3 so I'm wondering if I need to buy Intellij to develop a secure app.

I can't see why it would be less secure but I figured I should ask to make sure.

Comment: define "secure"... there is hardly an answer to this question, since we don't know your application.  for the other "implicit" questions/points here: a) consider using http://gvmtool.net/ to get your latest groovy things. b) grails 3 is a radical change over grails 2 and also intellij does not support it right now. c) check the changelog from 2.4.4 to 2.4.5 or 2.5 to see for yourself what changed, don't forget to also check your used plugins for changes, that concern security of *your application*.

Answer (score 2):

Your application is more likely to be the source of vulnerability than the platform you're using.

That being said, using outdated versions of a platform is asking for trouble. Unless 2.4.4 is actively being developed and supported, it is potentially less secure than new versions.